# about djoint operator

Tags: normed-spaces

I'm trying to prove that if $X,Y$ are normed spaces and $T:X\to Y$ is linear operator (assume bounded, if needed), then $T^*$ linear.

What i've been trying so far is taking $Tx_1,...,Tx_n$ a basis to $ImT$ and try to construct linear functionals $f_1,...f_n\in X^*$ corresponding to $x_1,...,x_n$ which means $f_i(x_j)=\delta_{ij}$ or $|f_i(x_i)|=\|x_i\|$, etc... Using some consequences of hahn-banach, and similar theorems..

Thanks for your help

Comment: Can you do the case of rank $1$?  And then can you do the general case using that?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning: You do not need to use $T,T^{*}$ are compact. In fact you can show any compact operator in Hilbert space is a limit of finite rank operator. It is easier to use the fact $T$ is finite rank and you do not need to appeal to big theorems. The fact $|T|=|T^{*}|$ should be automatic once you finish the proof.

Comment: "P.S" should be a separate question.

Comment: It's [already been asked](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1025776/147263). I will go compile an answer there.

Comment: Use $T^{**} = T$ for that.

Comment: gentle could mean explicit in this context

Comment: Review the definition of adjoint (between Hilbert spaces) to see why $T$ satisfies the definition of the adjoint of $T^*$.

Comment: You changed the question to a different one, which is no longer answered by the answer you marked as accepted. This is illogical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without working with a basis explicitly, one can argue as follows. Let $V=T(X)$. Let $R:Y^*\to V^*$ be the restriction operator, namely $R\phi = \phi_{|V}$. The range of $R$ is finite-dimensional, since $V^*$ is finite-dimensional. By definition of $T^*$, we have $T^*\phi = \phi\circ T = (R\phi)\circ T$. Thus, $T^*$ is the composition of finite-rank operator $R$ with another linear operator.